# Which path to access e.x. pictures from the whatsapp folder with StorageFolder.GetFolderFromPathAsync()

Tags: c#, windows-8.1, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

I tried to access files from a folder which is located in the KnownFolder.Pictures folder, e.x. files from Pictures/Whatsapp. I want to create a StorageFolder, but from which path?

here is my code, which does not work

```
StorageFolder picturesFolder = await StorageFolder.GetFolderFromPathAsync("Data///Pictures//Whatsapp");
```

thanks in advance,
Christian

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PicturesLibrary is an virtual location - it exists both on Phone and SD card. So it's hard to tell the direct path as it may depend on user settings. You can access your folder like this:

```
StorageFolder pictures = KnownFolders.PicturesLibrary;
StorageFolder folder = await pictures.GetFolderAsync(@"Whatsapp"); // now you should have your folder

// to create a folder:
StorageFolder newOne = await folder.CreateFolderAsync(@"NewFolder", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
```

Also remember to add suitable capabilities (*PicturesLibrary*) in your *package.appxmanifest* file.

As for your way - it is possible to get folder from direct path (if you had saved it before), but you have to give the complere path eg. `C:\Pictures...` - but as I've said above, Pictures can also exist on SD card which has different letter.

Comment: Thank you, it works perfect. Great answer as each time